# How to check in MS SQL whether text or excel file is open or is being used by some user

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I have a process where i will be reading data from files using bulk insert in MS SQL, this process runs in a job. But i am facing issue with this, some times the user keeps the files open during the job run and it fails.I want to implement a process where it checks for if the file is being currently used by some user before doing bulk insert, if yes then send out an mail alert saying 'xxx' user is using 'yyy' file name.Once the user closes the file then continue with the normal process rather than erroring out.

Comment: Have you tried using `TRY CATCH` to catch the BCP error? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 Then you can use database mail to send an email... although you won't know who has it locked, you'll only know that it's locked. Does this import occur at a scheduled time?

Comment: Yes,import occurs during scheduled time.

Comment: You can't (easily) work out who has a file open from SQL Server. You might be able to use the `sp_OACreate` stored procs to do this but it's not a good idea. You're probably better building some external powershell to do this and call it beforehand